# Session data showing in wrong customer in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: cart, customer-session

One of my websites built with Magento 1.7.0.2, that's sharing/showing wrong customer session data. If a customer Sign In but sometimes showing he/she didn't Sign In. Even Customer Shopping Cart data showing the wrong products.

Please help. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: do you use varnish cache?

Comment: No, we use Litespeed & CloudFlare.

Comment: are you able to reproduce this issue without CloudFlare? My first guess is, that the data are cached. Maybe you have to load dynamic date with ajax.